# UIImagePickerController lets me take photos and videos but will not let me save them or "use" them

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm working on a simple photo and video capture app right now. The app successfully allows the user to take a photo or video on a button press. However, as soon as you finish taking your photo or video, it gives 2 options: "Retake" and "Use Photo" or "Use Video", depending on which one you're using.

If the user taps "Retake" then it just let's them retake a new photo or video, but when the user taps "Use photo" or "Use video" it doesn't do anything. The app just takes them back to the main app screen.

I am confused on how to access the "Use photo" / "Use Video" button so that I can edit it's code and have it save images and video to camera roll.

Here is the code that I have so far:

**ViewController.h:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>

@property UIImagePickerController * pickerController;

-(IBAction)showCameraUI;

@end
```

**ViewController.m:**

```
#import "ViewController.h"


@interface ViewController () <UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

[UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
[UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];

NSLog(@"%ld", (long)UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera); }

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(IBAction)showCameraUI{

UIImagePickerController * pickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];

pickerController.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController  availableMediaTypesForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];

pickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;


[self presentViewController:pickerController animated:YES completion:NULL];

}

@end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` delegate of `UIImagePickerController` to save the image.

For this you need to do like:

```
-(IBAction)showCameraUI
{
    UIImagePickerController * pickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    pickerController.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    pickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    pickerController.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:pickerController animated:YES completion:NULL];

}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
   // save photo
    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
   if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage])
   {
       UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
       UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image,nil,nil,nil);
   }
   [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but what goes in the "save photo" body of the function?

Comment: @user3117509: I added that too, please check

Comment: I copy/pasted your code in but it doesn't like "mediaType". It says "Use of undeclared identifier 'mediaType'"

Comment: I just added your new fix, and the problem went away, but not it is giving me the same error for "kUTTypeImage"

Comment: @user3117509 Add the 'MobileCoreServices.framework' frame work and import the `#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>`

Comment: That fixed it! I just went and ran the app again on my iPhone. When I tapped "use photo" it asked if it could access my photos, I said "Ok" and then it just freezes. The frozen screen shows the picture I took and the "retake" and "Use Photo" buttons but that's it.

Comment: @user3117509: it freezes because it takes some time to save the photo and it is running on main thread. You can use the ALAssetLibrary to fix the freezing issue

Comment: Thank you for the help. I have just posted a new question on how to use the ALAssetLibrary to fix the freezing issue. The question can be found here and I would appreciate your input. Thank you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20790004/app-using-uiimagepickercontroller-freezes-when-selecting-use-photo-after-takin

Answer (score 3):

Please try to use this

```
- (void)captureVideoOrPhoto{
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    [imagePicker setDelegate:self];

    if (self.isSourceTypeCamera) {
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    }else{
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    }

    if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]&&self.isSourceTypeCamera){

        [imagePicker setShowsCameraControls:YES];
        [imagePicker setMediaTypes:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie,(NSString*)kUTTypeImage, nil]];

        if (self.isVideoMode) {
            imagePicker.videoMaximumDuration = 300;
            [imagePicker setCameraCaptureMode:UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModeVideo];
        }else{
            [imagePicker setCameraCaptureMode:UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto];
        }
        [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
    }else{
        if (self.isVideoMode) {
            [imagePicker setMediaTypes:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, nil]];
        }
        [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

    if (CFStringCompare ((__bridge CFStringRef) mediaType, kUTTypeMovie, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo) {
        NSURL *videoUrl=(NSURL*)[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
        NSString *moviePath = [videoUrl path];

        if (UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum (moviePath)) {
            UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum (moviePath, nil, nil, nil);
        }

        NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoUrl];
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *strFile = [Shared getAUniqueFileName];
        NSString *tempPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:@"/%@.mp4",strFile];

    }else if (CFStringCompare ((__bridge CFStringRef) mediaType, kUTTypeImage, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo){
        NSLog(@"image captured");

        UIImage *image = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.0);
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *strFile = [Shared getAUniqueFileName];
        NSString *tempPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:@"/%@.jpeg",strFile];
        [imageData writeToFile:tempPath atomically:NO];
    }

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Upload file(video, image) using AFNetworking 3.0

```
 AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    AFHTTPRequestSerializer *serializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
    [serializer setValue:@"video/mp4" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    manager.requestSerializer = serializer;
    NSString *strUrl = @"pass url";

    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"TestVideo" ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

    NSDictionary *param = @{@"method":@"uploadMedia",@"media_comment":@"hi",@"fileToUpload":fileData};

    [manager POST:strUrl parameters:param progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {
        NSLog(@"preogress %f",uploadProgress.fractionCompleted);

    } success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"uploaded successfully");

    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
        NSLog(@"fail to upload");
    }];
```